# Optimal way to group points in the plane into clusters

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, packing-and-covering

Consider a strictly decreasing sequence $d = (d_k)_{k\ge 1}$ of distances in $(0,1)$. Given a constant $C>2$, we say that $d$ has the **$C$-grouping property** if any finite non-empty subset $S$ (of the unit disc in $\mathbb C$) is clustered around some subset $S'\subset S$ in the sense that: (1) $|x - y|\ge Cd_{|S'|}$ for any $x\ne y$ in $S'$ and (2) every $z\in S$ has a unique $x\in S'$ with $|z - x|\le d_{|S'|}$.

For example, we can show that the sequence $(e_C)_k = C^{-k}$ has the $C$-grouping property for any $C>2$. Indeed, take a maximal (with respect to inclusion) subset $S'\subset S$ such that we have $|x - y|> C^{1-|S'|}$ for all $x\ne y$ in $S'$. Then, given any point $z\in S\setminus S'$, we must have $\inf_{x\in S'}|z-x|\le C^{-|S'|}$ since otherwise we can add $z$ to $S'$ (contradicting its maximality). Note that in this example, for any given $C$, the sequence $e_C$ decays exponentially to $0$ as $k\to\infty$.

**Is it possible to find examples of $C$-grouping sequences $d$, for any given $C\ge 3$, which don't decay exponentially (e.g., which have a lower bound like $e^{-ck^\alpha}\lesssim d_k$ for some $0<\alpha<1$ and $c>0$)? Going a bit further, can we find examples which decay only polynomially in $k$, i.e., which satisfy a lower bound of the form $k^{-\beta}\lesssim d_k$ for some $\beta>0$?**

Considering the example of the point set $S = \{-1,-\frac{n-1}{n}, \ldots,0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$ suggests that, for any $C$-grouping sequence $d$, we have $\sup_{k} kd_k<\infty$. **Is it actually possible to find a choice of $C\ge 3$ and a $C$-grouping sequence $d$ which has a lower bound $1/k\lesssim d_k$?** I expect (intuitively) that the answer is no, but would be interested to know an actual argument either way.